# Highcharts datalabels appearing below 0 on x axis

Tags: highcharts

Has anybody had this problem with highcharts, have specified rotated data labels with x:0, y:27 values but now I am getting labels appearing below 0 on x axis.  Tested with jsfiddle and they don't appear but on my build I am seeing this - see attached image.

[image]

How do I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you try to make it replicable on jsfiddle? Maybe you are using a different highcharts version on your build.

Comment: Hi Roco, I tried it on jsFiddle and I did not get the same problem.  Yes I will check versions, little annoying bug and it only happens on my build, oh joy!  Thanks.

Comment: Your problem is possible to recreate if you set `dataLabels.crop` to `false` - example: http://jsfiddle.net/wrommsrw/ (uncomment JS line 14 to see the problem). Maybe you are using this setting? If not, then a live example will be needed.